# How to optimize the SubQuery that returns the same result for each outer select

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-optimization

I'm not expert SQL user so I'm seeing some advice to optimize the below SQL.

```
SELECT pm.name, pm.WTPARTNUMBER 
FROM WTPARTMASTER pm, WTPART pt, CHECKOUTLINK clink
WHERE pt.IDA2A2 = clink.CLASSNAMEKEYROLEBOBJECTREF
AND pm.WTPARTMASTER
  IN (
    SELECT master.WTPARTNUMBER
    FROM WTPARTMASTER master 
    WHERE master.IDA2A2 
       NOT IN (
          SELECT ulink.IDA3B5
          FROM WTPARTUSAGELINK ulink, wtpart part
          WHERE part.IDA3E2ITERATIONINFO = 1
          AND ulink.CLASSNAMEKEYROLEAOBJECTREF = part.IDA2A2
       )
    AND master.WTPARTNUMBER LIKE '%-R'
  )
AND pm.WTPARTNUMBER LIKE '%-R'
ORDER BY pm.WTPARTNUMBER;
```

The first inner select returns the around 60K numbers which will be used in outer query IN.

Is there way I can execute the first inner query and use that result in the outer IN operator?

Or any other way to optimize the query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you established that Oracle isn't optimising it for you? Have you got an execution plan that shows it's being executed multiple times?

Comment: try using exists instead of IN https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: There's no join-condition for `WTPARTMASTER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slow:

```
where somefield not in 
(
select somefield
etc
)
```

This is faster:

```
where somefield in 
(
select somefield
from etc
where the conditions match the outer query
minus
select somefield
from etc
where the conditions match the outer query
and you want to exclude them
)
)
```